# Any concrete example(s) of $K3$ surfaces with Picand number 18 and does not admit Shioda-Inose structure?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

I am looking for some explicit examples of (elliptic) $K3$-families defined over a number field (better to be over $\mathbb{Q}$) with Picard number $18$ but does not admit Shioda-Inose structure, i.e. there is no primitive embedding from the transcendental lattice to $U^3$ ($U$ is the hyperbolic lattice). I am wondering is there good reference for that?

Sorry if the question is too trivial.

Comment: This should be asked on MO.

Comment: From the last line, my guess is that maybe the poster thought they were on MO!

Comment: This has been posted to MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311987/concrete-example-of-k3-surfaces-with-picard-number-18-and-does-not-admit-shiod) and is still open as of the time of this comment.